# Android: R.drawable.marker cannot be resolved or is not a field

Tags: android

Borrowing this code from several different tutorials on how to use Google maps on Android, I ran into a problem that "R.drawable.marker cannot be resolved or is not a field"

R.java is not being imported via the known bug in Eclipse.

```
public void onStart() {
     super.onStart();

         // Create an ItemizedOverlay to display a list of markers
           Drawable defaultMarker = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.marker);
           HelloItemizedOverlay placesItemizedOverlay = new HelloItemizedOverlay (defaultMarker, this);
           GeoPoint point =new GeoPoint((int)(41.856451 * 1E6),
                    (int)(-87.604864 * 1E6));
           OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(point, "Line 1", "Line 2");
           List<Overlay> mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();

           placesItemizedOverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);
           mapOverlays.add(placesItemizedOverlay);
          // mapView.getOverlays().add(placesItemizedOverlay);

 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a `marker.png` (or `marker.jpeg` or whatever) file in one or more of the `drawable*` directories in your project.

Comment: You just beat me to answering my own question, my hats off to you sir